# toByteArray equivalent in objective c

Tags: java, ios, objective-c

I'm currently working on an android and iOS project concurrently and I'm struggling to get the data encodings to work out. I have the following in Java:

```
byte[] asByteArray = toByteArray("48656c6c6f576f72");
System.out.println("Byte Decode array" + Arrays.toString(asByteArray));
```

In the console this provides me with the following:

> Byte Decode array[72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100]

Now in objective c I'm not entirely certain how to get the NSData equivalent for this?

```
 NSData *plainData = [plainText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"Plain text decoded: %@",plainData);
```

And I get the following:

> Plain text decoded: <32316564 35653765 31343664 63643335>

Any idea on how I can get the toByteArray function equivalent in Objective C?

Update:Add hex to base 10 String representation

```
- (NSString *)hexResponseToDecimalNSData:(NSString *) response {
    NSMutableString *decimalResponse = [NSMutableString string];


    for(int i = 0; i < response.length; i+=2){
        NSString *substringResponse = [response substringWithRange:NSMakeRange((NSUInteger) i, 2)];

        unsigned result = 0;
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:substringResponse];
        [scanner scanHexInt:&result];
        [decimalResponse appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d ",result]];
    }

    return decimalResponse
}
```

This function gets me one step closer to something like the toByteArray function Java.So if I supply it

> bbad42dfbf6e2680

it will return

> 187 173 66 223 191 110 38 128

. My question now is how would one take this 187 173 66 223 191 110 38 128 and represent it as NSData? i.e. as an 8 byte NSData?

Comment: Check NSData `bytes` (plainData.bytes)

Comment: What is your question now? Do you want the nsstring & nsdata for this array: 187 173 66 223 191 110 38 128 ?

Answer (score 1):

Java is treating the string as hex, each two characters as a hex value and displaying as a signed decimal value. The ObjC dataUsingEncoding is interpreting each character individually.

Objective-C does not supply hex conversion methods so one needs to write one.

Here is a hex string to `NSData` implementation Apple uses:

```
NSData * dataFromHexString(NSString *hexString) {
    char buf[3];
    buf[2] = '\0';
    unsigned char *bytes = malloc([hexString length]/2);
    unsigned char *bp = bytes;
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < [hexString length]; i += 2) {
        buf[0] = [hexString characterAtIndex:i];
        buf[1] = [hexString characterAtIndex:i+1];
        char *b2 = NULL;
        *bp++ = strtol(buf, &b2, 16);
    }

    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:bytes length:[hexString length]/2 freeWhenDone:YES];
}
```

Example:

```
NSString *hexString = @"21ed5e7e146dcd35";
NSLog(@"hexString: %@", hexString);
NSData *plainData = dataFromHexString(hexString);
NSLog(@"plainData: %@", plainData);
```

Output:
    hexString: "21ed5e7e146dcd35"
    plainData: <21ed5e7e146dcd35>

Note, the following are the same, just a different representation:

```
signed bytes:     33,  -19,   94,  126,   20,  109,  -51,   53
unsigned bytes:   33,  237,   94,  126,   20,  109,  205,   53
hex bytes:      0x21, 0xed, 0x5e, 0x7e, 0x14, 0x6d, 0xcd, 0x35
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is asking, there seems to be confusion between display encodings and data. Also the question data has been changed.